# Accept a screen share pop up

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm building a screen sharing app.

How do I accept the browser pop up from `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` with `rspec` and `capybara`?

[image]

I've attempted `page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept` and `page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t. It’s not a pop up that’s defined in the webdriver spec so there’s no way currently to interact with it. Instead you may be able to use Chromes WebRTC testing command line arguments to automatically skip the prompt and provide a fake media stream - https://webrtc.org/getting-started/testing